# Library not found for -lReact-RCTActionSheet after upgrading React Native 0.63.3 (From 0.61.5)

Tags: react-native, upgrade

I have just upgraded React native version 0.63.3 from version 0.61.5 using react native upgrade helper. I can run android work perfectly but running ios show an error : Library not found for -lReact-RCTActionSheet.

I tried some advices such as add something to Header Search Path, check build system setting ... But it does not work.

Please any one help me to fix it. Thanks so much!

[image]

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.63.3

https://blog.cpming.top/p/react-native-0-62-undefined-symbol

Comment: Can you please add your library search path screenshot too?